# Inverse of Boolean matrix

Tags: matrix

I have a boolean matrix A and I want to find the inverse of it A' (boolean matrix) where A.A' = I , I is the identity matrix and (.) operation is the boolean product of matrices (boolean product of matrices is like the traditional product of matrices but with addition replaced with the operation OR and with multiplication replaced with the operation AND).

Is there any simple way to calculate the inverse of boolean matrix?

Comment: I fear there is no simple way...

Comment: Ok, so ..  any useful way

Answer (score 3):

EDIT 2: found article with solution http://journals.cambridge.org/download.php?file=%2FGMJ%2FGMJ6_01%2FS2040618500034705a.pdf&code=6526701052e00037d69390f92ddf4fcd

TLDR - the only inversible boolean matrices are such, that A * transposed A = I.

So you can just transpose your matrix A, and if At * A != I it means A wasn't inversible

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. You are right about matrices which have one “1” at each row or column, but what I need is to get the inverse of the following matrix:
01011111
00111111
01110111
10011011
11001110
11100101
10000111
01100011

Comment: I’m  studying about public key encryption and digital signature based on Boolean functions and I read this paper  “Fast asymmetric cryptosystem based on Boolean product of matrices” 
In this study, they use this matrix and its inverse without showing it and the way to find it.

Comment: Read the link - it has theorem that says either the inverse of A is transposed A, or there's no inverse at all.

Comment: Also I think this matrix you wrote isn't inversible because it's product with transposition of itself isn't identity matrix.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I got the answer from that paper. You are right that if the matrix A has an inverse it must be At (A transpose).
But which is really strange is that in the paper : "Fast asymmetric cryptosystem based on Boolean product of matrices" they used the matrix I mentioned in a previous comment and its inverse !!!!
The link of the paper "Fast asymmetric cryptosystem based on Boolean product of matrices":
http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/login.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5069354&url=http%3A%2F%2Fieeexplore.ieee.org%2Fxpls%2Fabs_all.jsp%3Farnumber%3D5069354

Comment: Maybe they meant inverse in different sense?

Comment: I find that there are two definitions of the multiplication of Boolean matrices:
the first is obtained in an analogous way to the ordinary product of matrices, but with addition replaced with the operation OR and with multiplication replaced with the operation AND.
the second is obtained in an analogous way to the ordinary product of matrices, but with addition replaced with modulo 2 addition.

Comment: So, multiplication on {0, 1} is AND anyway, but addition mod 2 is XOR instead of OR, so there's a way to get 0 from row and column with even number of matching 1s.That's probably this definition then.

I'll try to think of some way to inverse matrix with such multiplication.

Comment: Exactly...
You can find the inverse using the identity matrix
http://home.comcast.net/~bpayne37/whitman59/gfsr/gfsrinvert.htm